# LWJGL Program stops working (without changing code) [ECLIPSE]

Tags: java, eclipse, glsl, lwjgl

Ever since I updated eclipse to Mars it's been having a lot issues, Right now I have an LWJGL program, If I launch it after I just opened eclipse, It works just fine, But if I relaunch it afterwards the program displays black, I haven't even changed the code it just stops working, And if I change the code and undo it and launch then it works, But relaunching again makes it stop working again.
WHAT IS THIS MADNESS?!

Answer (score 1):

I had a lot issues with Mars, and now I am using Luna on my linux. Eveything work. But try to reinstall mars. Maybe it solve your problems.

Comment: I just downgraded to Luna, If it doesn't work i'll go back to Kepler. The new versions are very bad :/